# $\int_{|z|=10} \frac{z^2-2z}{(z+1)^2(z^2+4)}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I want to find the value of the following complex integral,

$$\int_{|z|=10} \frac{z^2-2z}{(z+1)^2(z^2+4)}$$

I want to use the Cauchy Integral Formula.

> $$f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\Gamma \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)}dz$$

Attempt:

$$g(z)=\frac{z^2}{(z+1)^2(z^2+4)}-\frac{2z}{(z+1)^2(z^2+4)}$$

where

Now $z^2+4=(z+2i)(z-2i)$

$$g_1(2i)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{\frac{z^2}{(z+1)^2(z+2i)}}{(z-2i)}dz$$

$$g_2(2i)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{\frac{2z}{(z+1)^2(z+2i)}}{(z-2i)}dz$$

$g_1=\frac{z^2}{(z+1)^2(z+2i)}$ and $g_2=\frac{2z}{(z+1)^2(z+2i)}$

So value of integral is just $$2\pi i(g_1(2i)-g_2(2i))$$

Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cauchy integral formula requires that $f$ is holomorphic on the domain delimited by the curve $\Gamma$. The functions $g_1,g_2$ that you defined don't satisfy this, since they both have order $2$ poles at $z=-1$. You should try to decompose $\frac{1}{(z+1)^2(z^2+1)}$ into partial fractions and then use Cauchy integral formula.

Answer (score 2):

The value of such integral is simply zero, since the integrand function is $O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$ as $|x|\to +\infty$ and the integration contour encloses all the poles of the integrand function. See "*residue at infinity*".

Comment: I am self studying and I have not read that part.